# Using 2 Tank Circuits to Determine the Position/Direction of a Wire

Tags: proximity-sensor, emf

I am building a robot that uses 2 LC tank circuits with some gain and analog filtering to determine the position of a "Track Wire" that has an AC current of a specific frequency traveling vertically. The idea is to detect the wire and by using the difference in reading strengths between the two circuits, determine if the robot must turn left or right. I am trying to avoid simply having one tank circuit and having the robot "snake" left and right while aiming for the peak reading. 
My problem is that even after calibrating the sensors I get a very strange effect as the robot nears the wire.

The issue I'm having is that the difference between the analog readings from the left and right sensors zeros out at 3 different orientations. At first I thought I had switched my right and left inputs but after doing some tests, using the very simplified logic of if(left sensor>right center){print left}else{print right} I found the detection arc to look like this picture below. 
[image]

Is this because of the shape of the EMF from the track wire? Is there a reliable way to detect the direction of a wire using tank circuits or is there a better method?

[image]

edit: Updated the picture to show the direction of the robot and the positioning of the inductors. 
edit 2: Also I forgot to mention that there is a peak detector prior to the analog input of the microcontroller. I have uploaded the full schematic (its the same circuit twice)

Comment: Please explain the diagram. Maybe show the coils on it and indicate the tracker wire.

Comment: It must have something to do with the physics of your geometry which is unknown. . You show a radial plot but probably have an orthogonal inverse squared sensitivity that swaps orientation when you rotate the robot.

Comment: I think you want the loop with the weakest signal to indicate side of robot away from centre line, not the strongest and loop design is important. the loops should also be almost vertical or **slight tilt and spaced apart** to receive flux from wire to loop centre axis rather than from fringe edges of loop far away. The derivative of L/R and expected polarity will tell you if you are moving in the wrong direction.

Comment: You also need to say how you are getting " the analog readings". You can get them by amplitude and by phase. Which are you using?

Comment: As a coil crosses the wire the signal goes from perpendicular to the coil (makes voltage) to parallel (no voltage) so as you cross the wire, the individual coils go: weak - strong -  weak(right over wire)  - strong - weak

Comment: Hint: use phase - it gives you direction info.

Comment: My analog readings are simply amplitude not phase. I updated the diagram to show that when the robot is facing forward with the inductors spaced a few inches apart, these are the readings I will get when the wire is placed in each section of the arc.

Answer (score 1):

You have a flaw in your coil design. If the wire passes between the two receive coils at dead centre (irrespective of angle) you receive the same voltage for each coil: -

[image]

In any of the trajectories above you will get a reading of "middle".

You can partially fix this with fore and aft coils added to your design and processed seperately. I say "partially" but there will still be a false neutral position at 90 degrees.